# How can I create a copy of an Oracle table include trigger,sequence & index

Tags: oracle

I know the statement:

```
create table x as select * from y where 1=0;
```

Which copies the structure but will not copy the trigger,sequence & index

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You should use DBMS_METADATA package (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/metadata_api.htm#SUTIL3619)

Some tutorial here: http://www.orafaq.com/node/807

You could also use SQL Developer and there is tab "SQL" for every table. Inside "SQL" is sql which contains all dependencies to recreate your table

Comment: This info, known as DDL, is available in other IDEs such as Toad, as well as accessible from CL tools like sqlplus. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_1001.htm#SQLRF30001